# Visit function that takes a std::variant an arbitrary number of callbacks and matches one of the variant's altenatives

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, variant, visitor-pattern

I've been trying this for a while, but I just can't get it to work.

In Visual Studio 2017, how can I create a 'Visit' function that takes a std::variant and an arbitrary number of callbacks and calls the correct one with the extracted variant value.

These are the things that I'm looking to achieve:

- Visit would take the variant and one or more callbacks.
- Only the callback matching the current variant value would be called.
- If there are no matching functions, nothing would be called.
- The compiler selects the callback at compile-time, not runtime.
- Is ok if there is a compilation error if a callback was passed whose param does not match any of the variant types.
- Bonus: Support a callback that takes no param and is called if no type was matched.

The calling code would be like this:

```
// std::monostate represents nil value.
using VarT = std::variant<std::monostate, bool, int_t, double, std::string_view>;
VarT var = ...

Visit(var,
    [](int_t) {},
    [](std::string_view) {},
    // [](Foo&), // Is ok if this gives error, as Foo is not a type in VarT
    []() {} // Bonus: the default case, if var is not an int_t or a string_view
);
```

There are examples there ->
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit,
but Visual Studio 2017 does not support some of the new features needed to do that.

Comment: I have just come across this: https://gist.github.com/cdacamar/584c6d43a9cca1ccffec3b36ad5dfe3f It works for me :)

Comment: probably moot at this point, but the latest visual studio 2017 15.3 can compile those examples.